# Adding an image in WPF USING MVVM through BindableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What I'm trying to do is adding an image every time I click on an add button to a `StackPanel` from a `BindableCollection`. I tried using an `ItemsControl` as shown in the code bellow:

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="Tickets">

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageTicket,diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>   
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Nothing is showing though I tried to trace the output but it seems there is no issue.

Here's my ViewModel Class:

```cs
class POSViewModel : Screen
{   
    public BindableCollection<TicketModel> Tickets { get; set; }

    public POSViewModel()
    {

        Tickets = new BindableCollection<TicketModel>();
    }



    public void ManBtn()
    {
        TicketModel Ticket = new TicketModel
        {
            CategorieEnum = CategorieEnum.man,
            ImageSource = "/Assets/Icons/man.png",
            Prix = 10,
            TicketId = 0
        };
        Tickets.Add(Ticket);

    }
}
```

and here's my model class:

```cs
class TicketModel 
{
    private int ticketId;
    private CategorieEnum catégorieName;
    private float prix;
    private string imageSource;
    private Image imageTicket;

    public Image ImageTicket
    {
        get {
            Image Img = new Image();
            Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageSource, UriKind.Relative));
            return Img;
        }
        set { ImageTicket = value; }
    }


    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public CategorieEnum CategorieEnum { get; set; }
    public float Prix { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

**PS :** I'm using [Caliburn.micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) framework.

Edit1 : I also tried binding the `ImageSource`, still no images are displayed.

Comment: Is `ManBtn()` getting called? By the way, you shouldn't create a new `Image` in the getter.

Comment: i'm not sure how can i verify that?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the method and debug?

Comment: Nothing in the supplied code is setting the private imageSource field which you're using as the source for your BitmapImage.

Comment: apprently ManBtn doesnt get called i'll have to figure out why

Comment: @OujnineMohamed Is there any specific reason why you changed the accepted answer? The one you accepted now doesn't contribute anything relevant beyond what was already said in the other. The rest is just what you already had.

Comment: @Clemens i'm sorry i didn't know that would change the accepted answer i thought that this highlight both answers as correct..i'm novice  to stackoverflow so please pardon me if i caused some misconvenience or misunderstanding, i'll change it again since your answer fits more..sorry again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ImageTicket` property declaration is wrong. It should return an ImageSource:

```
public ImageSource ImageTicket
{
    get { return new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImageSource, UriKind.Relative)); }
}
```

The setter did not make any sense, because it did nothing but recursively calling itself.

The whole property may be redundant, since due to built-in automatic type conversion you could also directly bind to the `ImageSource` property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
```

But be aware that if you use a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) in code behind, it should be fully prefixed:

```
ImageSource = "pack://application:,,,/Assets/Icons/man.png",
```

and the image file's Build Action should be set to *Resource*.

Comment: thank you i'll try this after i figure out why my button isn't being called

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code that can be helpful, but it uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollction`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets}" x:Name="RecipeItemControl" Height="100">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The view model is modified as:

```
public class POSViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Property Changed Event Handler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TicketModel> _Tickets { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TicketModel> Tickets {
        get {
            return _Tickets;
        }
        set {
            _Tickets = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tickets));
        }
    }

    public POSViewModel() {
        Tickets = new ObservableCollection<TicketModel>();
    }

    public void Add() {

        TicketModel Ticket = new TicketModel
        {
            ImageSource = @"H:\Good.png",
            Prix = 10,
            TicketId = 0
        };
        Tickets.Add(Ticket);

    }

}



public class TicketModel
{
    private int ticketId;
    private float prix;
    private string imageSource;
    private ImageSource imageTicket;
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public float Prix { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: i was using almost the same code but i found some difficulties accessing to some vraibles in my project thats why i switched to BindableCollection..Anyway, thank you sir for the help, i'm very gratefull !

Comment: What was the issue in accessing variables, could you please explain

Comment: i was trying to sum the prices of the ticket collection then displaying it on a BlockText, however i was having some binding issues, please bare with me if my english is bad, also i'm still novice to Mvvm and wpf on general ^^